# How to fix assertTrue error when running Junit test

Tags: java, junit, assert

Setting up a Junit test but run into an test fail. Issue seems to be around my assertTrue

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Test;

import com.neueda.cap.spark.model.NeuFixMessage;

import quickfix.Message;

public class CalculateFillValue {

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        CalculateFillValuesMapper test = new CalculateFillValuesMapper();
        NeuFixMessage msg= new  NeuFixMessage();
        msg.setMsgType("8");
        msg.setExecType("1");
        msg.setLastPx("10.10");
        msg.setLastShares("100");

        msg = test.call(msg);
        assertTrue("The  file value should be 1010", msg.getFillValue() == 1010);



    }

}
```

Comment: I suggest using `assertEquals(message, expected, actual)` instead of `assertTrue(message, expected == actual)` as the error message from JUnit wil be better - you will get both the expected and actual value so you can compare as opposed to just 'false'.

Answer (score 0):

The Only reason your test should fail is when getFillValue() returns anything other than 1010. Print your output just above the assertTrue method and you should see why your test is failing.

```
System.out.println("Fill Value: " + msg.getFillValue());

boolean testCondition = (msg.getFillValue() == 1010)


System.out.println("testCondition: " + testCondition);

assertTrue("The  file value should be 1010", testCondition);
```

Comment: do u mean just a   System.out.println(1010);    ,  if so then my junit test passes

Comment: that fixed it- however i now am required to test it f i changed the message type to something invalid

Answer (score 0):

Is it better to use assertTrue or assertequals

current code is

assertEquals("This is the expected fill",msg.getFillValue(),(1010.0));

error: The method assertEquals(String, Object, Object) is ambiguous for the type CalculateFillValue